# Custom Camera view for UIImagePickerController that uses the base camera UI?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to build a slightly modified UIImagePickerController with a UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera source-type. I would like to retain the default controls of Flash, Front/Read facing camera, and Photo Capture but replace the default cancel button with a smaller cancel button & a button to launch the user's device photo-library. Is there a way to do this without having to recreate the entire camera UI? If there's not a way, is there a 3rd party library (commercial or open-source) that allows for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that there is no way to modify the standard camera UI unless you recreate it entirely, but I don't know if there is any library to help you with this. I had to create a new UI and I didn't find it difficult. You can easily bind the UI elements with the functionalities you need. [This](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821) might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for a library that recreates most of the default camera view (toggle between video / photo, flip for front-facing camera, flash, launch photo albums, etc.).